# Normalization in variable range [ x , y ] in Matlab

Tags: matlab, normalization

I wanna create basic matlab program that normalizes given array of integer in the given range.

- Inputs are an array [ a1 , a2 , a3 , a4 , a5 , a6 , a7... ], and the range [ x , y ]
- Output is normalized array.

But in everywhere, i see the normalization in the range of [0,1] or [-1,1]. Can't find variable range normalization. 
I will be grateful if you write the matlab code or the formula for variable range.

Thank you for ideas.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want to normalize to `[x, y]`, first normalize to `[0, 1]` via:

```
 range = max(a) - min(a);
 a = (a - min(a)) / range;
```

Then scale to `[x,y]` via:

```
 range2 = y - x;
 a = (a * range2) + x;
```

Putting it all together:

```
 function normalized = normalize_var(array, x, y)

     % Normalize to [0, 1]:
     m = min(array);
     range = max(array) - m;
     array = (array - m) / range;

     % Then scale to [x,y]:
     range2 = y - x;
     normalized = (array*range2) + x;
```

Comment: Great solution, but for moments it seemed Python and I copied-pasted without looking :P (and after I upvoted and commented I looked into the title and saw that was for matlab! sorry, though it was very helpful!)

Comment: What if I haven't the input range? Let's say that I'd like to put a number, for instance 345, in the range [-1,1]

Comment: @superpuccio: ? Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Two linear mappings can be combined into a single linear mapping. This seems like a wasteful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from R2017b, MATLAB has this function named [`rescale`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rescale.html) which does exactly this.
i.e. if you want to rescale `array` to the interval `[x, y]` then:

```
normalized_array = rescale(array, x, y);
```

If `x` and `y` are not specified then `array` gets normalized to the interval `[0,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has special function for Normalization, These include in Artificial Neural Network toolbox, which used for normalization input values.

**mapminmax**

mapminmax processes matrices by normalizing the minimum and maximum values of each row to [YMIN, YMAX].

**mapstd**

mapstd processes matrices by transforming the mean and standard deviation of each row to ymean and ystd.

[more information](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html)